# Calculate the uncertainty of a MLE

Tags: python, maximum-likelihood, uncertainty, fisher-information, hessian

I have minimized the negative LL of a Poisson distribution to get an MLE of three parameters using scipy.minimize w/ Nelder-Mead. I want to calculate the uncertainty of the MLE.

From reading, I think that I need to calculate the inverse Fisher matrix i.e the curvature of the negative LL at the MLE but I'm not sure how to go about this. Maybe use a package to calculate the Hessian at the MLE? Is there package,tool or standard method to calculate this in Python?

Comment: You can use either a library like autograd for an exact hessian, or numdifftools for an approximation using finite differences. I suggest the former, see a blog post here: https://rlhick.people.wm.edu/posts/mle-autograd.html

Comment: @Cam.Davidson.Pilon - this is worth expanding as an answer, as many practitioners are likely unaware of automatic differentiation, much less aware of packages and libraries that do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A contrived solution to my specific localization problem using @Cam.Davidson.Pilon's suggestion:

```
import numpy.linalg as lin
import autograd.numpy as np 
from autograd import grad, jacobian, hessian
from scipy.optimize import minimize

A = np.array([950])
src = np.array([14,8])
det = np.array([np.arange(5,20),np.arange(5,20)])
meas  = np.array((A/(np.square(src[0] - det[0,:])+np.square(src[1] - det[1,:])))

def log_likelihood(params):
    b = np.array([(params[0] / (np.square(params[1]- det[0,:]) + np.square(params[2] - det[1,:])))])
    L = np.array(np.sum(b - np.multiply(meas, np.log(b))))
    return L

x0 = np.array([800,11,5])
jacobian_ = jacobian(log_likelihood)
hessian_ = hessian(log_likelihood)

MLE = minimize(log_likelihood,x0,method='Nelder-Mead')
var = lin.inv(hessian_(MLE.x))
```

And a comparison with the inverse Hessian returned from L-BFGS-B solver method:

```
MLE = minimize(log_likelihood,x0,method='L-BFGS-B', bounds=[(0,10000),(-100,100),(-100,100)])

Hessian Inv:
 [[ 1.54249635e+04  2.99798625e+01 -3.35559404e+01]
 [ 2.99798625e+01  1.10393263e-01 -3.76041890e-02]
 [-3.35559404e+01 -3.76041890e-02  1.24504426e-01]]

MLE Hessian Inv: 
 [[ 1.45645563e+04  2.62311990e+01 -3.34866828e+01]
 [ 2.62311990e+01  1.00134010e-01 -3.37977338e-02]
 [-3.34866828e+01 -3.37977338e-02  1.25944847e-01]]
```

Comment: go further! `MLE = minimize(log_likelihood, x0, method='BFGS', jac=jacobian_)`

Comment: O yeah using the calculated autograd Jacobian improves the performance time but I did it without that to show that both methods agree... I needed a sanity check when doing it with my actual data where the returned Hessians from each method weren't in super close agreement

Comment: The lbfgsb hessian is a (sometimes poor) approximation - it’s not really meant to be used as a good approx to the hessian either. The autograd one is exact.